# How to print a long string in a single line in a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am recieving an OData file from a webservice and I want to create a .csv from that response. I was able to process the data correctly but some fields (TCComments and TCComentarioOrden) are written in the file in different lines. I tried using strip() and a function that I found but that did not fixed the issue

The function I tried was:

```
def escape_ansi(line):
    ansi_escape =re.compile(r'(\x9B|\x1B\[)[0-?]*[ -\/]*[@-~]')
    return ansi_escape.sub('', line)
```

This is the portion of code where I decode the JSon response and write it in a .csv file:

```
fo.write("CallID||EarlyStart||DueDate||LateStart||Priority||Region||District||Duration||Latitude||Longitude||Street||Status||TaskTypeCategory||AssignmentStart||AssignmentFinish||AssignedEngineer||TCCanal3||TCCanal50||TCCanal70||TCCanal110||TCCanal116||TCAccion||TCAfectacion||TCComments||TCtipoCierre||TCCodigoCierre||TCComentarioOrden\n")

for task in resultadoJson:
    CallID = task["CallID"]
    EarlyStart = task["EarlyStart"]
    DueDate = task["DueDate"]
    LateStart = task["LateStart"]
    Priority = str(task["Priority"])
    Region = task["Region"]["@DisplayString"]
    District = task["District"]["@DisplayString"]
    Duration = str(task["Duration"])
    Latitude = str(task["Latitude"])
    Longitude = str(task["Longitude"])
    Street = task["Street"]
    Status = task["DisplayStatus"]["@DisplayString"]
    TaskTypeCategory = task["TaskTypeCategory"]["@DisplayString"]
    AssignmentStart = task["AssignmentStart"]
    AssignmentFinish = task["AssignmentFinish"]
    try:
        AssignedEngineer =  task["AssignedEngineer"]["@DisplayString"]
    except:
        AssignedEngineer =  'Sin asignar'
    TCCanal3 = str(task["TCCanal3"])
    TCCanal50 = str(task["TCCanal50"])
    TCCanal70 = str(task["TCCanal70"])
    TCCanal110 = str(task["TCCanal110"])
    TCCanal116 = str(task["TCCanal116"])
    TCAccion =  task["TCAccion"]["@DisplayString"]
    TCAfectacion =  task["TCAfectacion"]["@DisplayString"]
    TCComments = escape_ansi(task["TCComments"])
    TCComments = TCComments.strip()
    try:
        TCtipoCierre =  task["TCtipoCierre"]["TCVisualName"]
    except:
        TCtipoCierre =  ''
    try:
        TCCodigoCierre =  task["TCCodigoCierre"]["TCVisualName"]
    except:
        TCCodigoCierre =  ''
    TCComentarioOrden = escape_ansi(task["TCComentarioOrden"])
    TCComentarioOrden= TCComentarioOrden.strip()
    fo.write(CallID+"||"+EarlyStart+"||"+DueDate+"||"+LateStart+"||"+Priority+"||"+Region+"||"+District+"||"+Duration+"||"+Latitude+"||"+Longitude+"||"+Street+"||"+Status+"||"+TaskTypeCategory+"||"+AssignmentStart+"||"+AssignmentFinish+"||"+AssignedEngineer+"||"+TCCanal3+"||"+TCCanal50+"||"+TCCanal70+"||"+TCCanal110+"||"+TCCanal116+"||"+TCAccion+"||"+TCAfectacion+"||"+TCComments+"||"+TCtipoCierre+"||"+TCCodigoCierre+"||"+TCComentarioOrden+"\n")

fo.close()
```

This is a sample from the field TCComments:

```
""TCComments": "Variacion en el SNR, generando conteo de errores.\n\nCable9/0/1-upstream0 (QU21A)\tqam64\t6.4\t24\t37.8\t1.7\t14\t100%\t33\tok\tok\t142\t   \nCable9/0/1-upstream1 (QU21A)\tqam64\t6.4\t24\t31.4\t1.8\t12\t94%\t37\tok\tok\t167\t   \nCable9/0/1-upstream2 (QU21A)\tqam64\t6.4\t24\t23.6\t1.5\t8\t89%\t33\tok\t7%\t247\t   \nCable9/0/1-upstream3 (QU21A)\tqam64\t3.2\t12\t18.8\t1.2\t6\t100%\t34\tok\tok\t227\t   \n""
```

And this is a sample from the field TCComentarioOrden:

```
 "TCComentarioOrden": "Óptico ubicado en condarco 2296. Se identifican puertos 4,5,2 y 1 con ingress más comprometidos. \nSe trabaja en puerto 4.\nHgd en ayolas 1672, se identifica salida main, aux1 y aux2 con ingress. \nSe filtra abonado de ayolas 1613 en tap 32x8 en misma altura. \nSe ajusta abonado flojo en tap 32x4 en ayolas misma altura de activo.\nSe ajusta abonado flojo en tap 20x8 en ayolas 1558.\nSe filtra abonado de condarco 2320 en tap 29x8 al 2332.\nHgd en Irala 1605, se identifica aux2 con ingress. \nSe ajusta abonado flojo en tap 32x8 en Irala 1662.\nSe trabaja puerto 5.\nHgd en ayolas 1879, se identifica aux1 y aux2 con ingress. \nSe ajusta abonado flojo en tap 11x2 final en av la plata 2204.\nSe filtra abonado de ayolas 1724 en tap 8x2 final en misma altura. \nHgd en husares 2570, se identifica aux1 y salida main con ingress. \nSe filtra abonado de triunvirato 1829 en tap 20x2 misma altura. \nSe filtra abonado de triunvirato 1757 en tap 32x4 en misma altura. \nSe debe continuar trabajando por lo tanto se suspende ticket. 5 filtros "
```

As you can see, those fields have escape characters.

This is what happens when I import the .csv file:

[image]

And i would like the import file to look like this:

[image]

Thank you kindly for your time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`str.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) method. `fo.write(TCComments.replace('\n', ''))`.

Alternatively, you can do it in `escape_ansi()` as well: `return ansi_escape.sub('', line).replace('\n', '')`.

(Of course, you may want to replace with a space (`' '`) instead of an empty string.)